# Flask email API, getting information from form tags

Tags: python, flask

I have a contact page, where I want some information sent to my email account when a user submits a message. I have a file send.py set up with the configuration so far just as a test.

**send.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app =Flask(__name__)
mail=Mail(app)

app.config.update(
DEBUG=True,
#EMAIL SETTINGS
MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
MAIL_PORT=465,
MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
MAIL_USERNAME = '(myemailaccount)',
MAIL_PASSWORD = '(mypassword)'
)

mail=Mail(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    msg = Message(
          'Hello',
       sender='(myemailaccount)',
       recipients=
           ['(myemailaccount('])
    msg.body = "This is the email body"
    mail.send(msg)
    return "Sent"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

On my **routes.py**, I have an **About** page, where I render an HTML template, with some `<form>` tags, that I want to display in the email, how can I render the HTML code into my **send.py**. Should I save it as arguments in my **routes.py** first? I should I add my **send.py** information inside of my **routes.py**?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show isolation of all project files in question. For eg. the above code should be highlighted as **send.py**, similarly show the routes.py code and the html form template code and give a heading for each code to show isolation. Finally, the indentation is also a bit off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs for flask-mail](https://pythonhosted.org/flask-mail/#flaskext.mail.Message), the `Message` class also accepts and `html` argument. All you need to do is assign a value of `render_template("home.html")` to send the rendered html page to the body of the email, assuming `home.html` is the **About** page. You must also make sure that `home.html` is inside the *templates* folder as Flask renders all html templates from this folder.

I present a small example. Note that I haven't used a separate **send.py** as I wanted to call the `send_message` function on a different route, so I added it to the same **routes.py** file:

**Project structure:**

```
root
└───templates
    |___ home.html
|___ routes.py
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Send Message</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-inline" action="/send_message" method="POST">
        <label>Enter name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary">
        <p>{{confirm_msg}}</p>
    </form>
    <script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app =Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
DEBUG=True,
#EMAIL SETTINGS
MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com',
MAIL_PORT=465,
MAIL_USE_SSL=True,
MAIL_USERNAME = 'myemailaccount',
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
)

mail=Mail(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/send_message", methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    msg = Message(
       subject='Hello ' + name,
       sender='myemailaccount',
       recipients=
           ['myemailaccount'],
       html=render_template("home.html"))
    mail.send(msg)
    confirm_msg = "Your message has been sent!"
    return render_template("home.html", confirm_msg=confirm_msg)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

**Explanation:**

The **home.html** page renders a simple form that accepts a `name`. This name is sent to the `send_message()` function using Flask's `request.form.get()` function. The name is then sent in the Subject line of the email. Notice the html argument in the `Message()` class, this sends the rendered form in the body of the email. Finally, a message is displayed confirming the message was sent. As this is a POST request(sending email), we must specify the method both in the `<form>` tag and the route `/send_message`. The `<form>` tag also has an `action` attribute that makes the function call to the `send_message()` function in the `/send_message` route when the form is submitted.

**Caveats:**

Make sure `mail=Mail(app)` is called after `app.config.update()` as shown in above code. This is to make sure the config settings are applied successfully before the `mail` object is created. Next, you may have to enable a security setting in your gmail account to be able to send the email(I had to do this) for testing purposes. This is because gmail will block any less secure apps that try to authenticate on your account. More details [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

I have tested the above code and successfully received the simple html `form` rendered in the body of the email.

Comment: Thank you for the very good explanation. The idea, is that I want to send an email to myself, with the information from the form tags, but I guess, I can just attach the attributes into the message body, like with the subject?

Comment: Yes, to capture form values you can use the 'name' attribute in the form and get that value in Flask using request.form.get() as I've done in the code too, to capture the name input for the subject line. What is the error?

Comment: whenever the email is sent, it is sent with 'None' parameters

Comment: however, this I when I add both 'POST' and 'GET' as parameters under methods, otherwise I get a METHOD NOT ALLOWED error

Comment: It works if i only put get in the METHODS parameter, but i still can't fetch any values